# fgetcsv() function is showing unwanted characters when I tried to show the CSV content after upload

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a CSV file and after upload the file I want to show the CSV file content in a `print_r()`.

But It's showing me some unwanted characters like that image. It should show me actual data in that CSV file

[image]

**The code I am using:**

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8');
if(isset($_POST["save"]) && $_POST['save'] == 'Upload CSV File' ){      
    echo $filename=$_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"];  

     if($_FILES["csv"]["size"] > 0)  {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            echo '<pre>';
                print_r($getData);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
        fclose($file);  
    }
}    
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Upload File</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="csv"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Upload CSV File"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSV file you're using does not appear to be an actual CSV file but some binary file. Only actual CSV files can be used.